# When Cassandra authentication enabled, opscenter can not connect to the cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Using Datastax Community Edition. When Password authentication is enabled, opscenter can not connect with cassandra. I can access cassandra through cqlsh shortcut where I provided username and password modifying shortcut's target field. Opscenter log refers that user not logged in. Is there any way to overcome it or it is stil a bug ?
[image: Opscenter log error]

Comment: Can you include the version numbers for OpsCenter and DataStax Community Edition? Also, how many nodes are running in your cluster?

Comment: @BrianC using _datastax-community-64bit_2.0.11_ for Windows7 64-bit Desktop PC. Just a single node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When connecting OpsCenter to a Cassandra cluster with authentication enabled, you can provide the username and password in the "Thrift username" and "Thrift password" options in the dialog:

[image: Thrift username/password in OpsCenter]

If you have previously connected OpsCenter to the Cassandra cluster and then later enabled authentication (which sounds like your case), you will need to add the username and password to the cluster configuration file for OpsCenter. You may need to restart OpsCenter after this change in order to pick it up. Follow the instructions in [Cassandra connection properties](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.0/opsc/configure/opscConnectionConfig_r.html) to add to cluster_name.conf file a section like:

```
[cassandra]
username = your-username-here
password = your-password-here
seed_hosts = node1,node2,node3
api_port = 9160
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I wish more people would use images to give examples like this.